# How to extract the CDATA using Script assertion?

Tags: soapui

I am getting the below response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetUKLocationByPostCodeResponse xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
         <GetUKLocationByPostCodeResult><![CDATA[<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Town>Grangetown</Town>
    <County>Cardiff</County>
    <PostCode>CF1</PostCode>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Town>Leckwith</Town>
    <County>Vale of Glamorgan</County>
    <PostCode>CF1</PostCode>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Town>Canton</Town>
    <County>Cardiff</County>
    <PostCode>CF1</PostCode>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Town>Cardiff</Town>
    <County>Cardiff</County>
    <PostCode>CF1</PostCode>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>]]></GetUKLocationByPostCodeResult>
      </GetUKLocationByPostCodeResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am able to extract the Town, County, PostCode using property Transfer..

But, How to extract the same using script assertion..

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
log.info(groovyUtils)
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("GetUKLocationByPostCode#ResponseAsXml")
log.info(holder)
def num = holder.getNodeValue("//Town")
log.info(num)
```

It is returning unexpected element cdata.. How to resolve this..?

Comment: Did you try the documentation? http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-cdata.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Achieved this by the below script:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
responsexmlholder = new XmlHolder(messageExchange.getResponseContentAsXml())
responsexmlholder.declareNamespace("ns1","http://www.webserviceX.NET")
Cdataxml = responsexmlholder.getNodeValue("//ns1:GetUKLocationByPostCodeResult")
Cdataxmlholder = new XmlHolder(Cdataxml)
Town = Cdataxmlholder.getNodeValue("//Town")
```

Comment: Just one note: generally you do not have to mess around with namespaces, and so you can do something like `responsexmlholder.getNodeValue("//*:GetUKLocationByPostCodeResult")` and skip the whole `responsexmlholder.declareNamespace(...)` business.